# Eclipse shows same source folder as multiple source folders while creating project using existing source code

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I have source code of a java project placed. I am creating a java project using that folder as follows:

```
File > New > Java Project >
```

and in project name field gave the name of the folder containing the source code and libs. There is a single src folder but eclipse treats a package in the source folder as a separate source folder. I want that it should have only single source folders with all the packages in the same folder, what could be the problem and how to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: This is not the way to import a project into eclipse.  If you want to do it this way, you're going to need to create the project where none exists and manually copy the source inside.  Alternatively you can import an existing project into the workspace.

Comment: @Neil Import existing projects into workspace option does not work unless there are eclipse specific project files are placed in the project folder.

Comment: Then my advice would be to create the java project from scratch, and copy and paste the source in the proper folders from the file system, then refresh the project.

Comment: this is the same problem I'm having and I have no idea why Eclipse can't properly import the code as-is. It's really frustrating.